# How method name is converted into a symbol in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to understand Ruby and it's not clear for me, how Ruby converts name of method into a `Symbol`?

In method definition we give it a name `meth`

```
module Mod
  def meth
    puts 'm'
  end
end
```

But if we want to check if a method exists, we pass the symbol `:meth` as a parameter to `method_defined`

```
Mod.method_defined?(:meth)
=> true
```

Please, help me understand, how does this work?

Comment: All the following answers are great, just saying, any string can be converted into a symbol using `"my_string".to_sym`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's not clear for me, how Ruby converts name of method into :symbol?

That's the way [`Method#name`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Method.html#method-i-name) works, it returns the name of the method as a symbol:

```
m = "foo".method(:size)     #=> #<Method: String#size>
m.name                      #=> :size
m.call                      #=> 3
```

All methods referencing other methods usually work this way. For example, [`Object#methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-methods) returns a array of method names:

```
"foo".methods
#=> [:<=>, :==, :===, :eql?, :hash, :casecmp, :+, :*, ...]
```

> In method definition we give it name `meth` ... but if we want check, does any method exist, we give into `method_defined` symbol `:meth`

`meth` would be a reference to a variable or another method, whereas `:meth` is just a symbol:

```
meth = :foo
Mod.method_defined? meth   #=> false, equivalent to Mod.method_defined? :foo
Mod.method_defined? :meth  #=> true
```

Comment: If I have two classes with different names, for example `Post` and `Comment`, and both have method with name `print` but with different functionality . And this two different methods links to only one symbol :print. Am I right?

Comment: Well, both methods have the same *name*, but the methods are different of course.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to ruby's method invocation syntax: You can call a method just by referencing its name, without any further syntax like brackets `()` needed.

Now, if the `method_defined?` method would take the method itself as an argument, there would be no way to do so without actually invoking the method and thereby producing an error if the method would not exist:

```
Mod.method_defined?(meth) 
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `meth'
```

With symbols, there is no invocation taking place, it is just normally instantiated and not producing any error. Behind the curtains, `method_defined?` can then lookup if a method exists by the name the symbol references without producing any error.

Comment: Where in C you can just use a name without brackets as a function pointer, other languages use different constructs. E.g. Perl would use `\&meth`. In both Perl and C, this is more direct than using a Ruby `Symbol` - it can be invoked by de-reference. Ruby does have an equivalent in `method(:foo)` e.g. `method(:meth).call`.

Answer (score 1):

[**`Module#method_defined?`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-method_defined-3F)

> method_defined?(symbol) → true or false
>
> method_defined?(string) → true or false
>
> Returns true if the named method is defined by mod (or its included modules and, if mod is a class, its ancestors). Public and protected methods are matched. ***String arguments are converted to symbols.***

That means- `method_defined?` method always expect *symbol* as its argument,but if you use *string*,then it is internally converted into a symbol using `String#to_sym`.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't so much that a method is "turned into" a symbol, it is just that it can be referred to by symbol.

When we look at the collection of methods from ObjectSpace.methods` we see that the objects are referred to as symbols.

This makes sense as symbols in Ruby are highly efficient as there is only one object that is that symbol, they are immutable, and it can refer to what it needs to depending on its context, referring to the scope and what 'self' is at the moment.

In other words, a symbol called `:to_s` will be the same symbol no matter where it is referred to.  It's object_id will always be the same, but it may refer to Array's `to_s` method or even a local variable called `to_s`.

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers also need to be stored in memory. All languages store method names, class names in some form or the other. They just don't make these accessible like Ruby.
Class names are stored as constants. Method names are stored as symbols. There is nothing such as being converted to Symbol. It is stored as symbol always. This makes following possible:

```
1.send(:+, 3) # exactly same as 1+3
```

This also means that you can actually accept names from user and execute that particular method. You were always able to do that via switch/if-else but this really removes a layer from functionality.
For example

```
case option
  when '+'
    variable1 + variable2
  when '-'
    variable1 - variable2
  when '*'
    variable1 * variable2
  when '/'
    variable1 / variable2
end
```

compared to

```
variable1.send(option, variable2)
```

Do you see the genius of it?